# C# GemBox-SpreadSheet Right To Left

Tags: c#, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

I'm using a C# WebApi 2, stored on Azure server without office installed.

I need to create an excel file, and know that GemBox Spreadsheet does not require office to be installed on the machine.

The issue is that I need the file to be right to left, and could not find how to do it.

Is it even possible with GemBox Spreadsheet?

If no, is there another library that does not require office that support RTL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ExcelFile file = new ExcelFile();
ExcelWorksheet sheet = file.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
ExcelViewOptions viewOptions = sheet.ViewOptions;

viewOptions.ShowColumnsFromRightToLeft = true;
```

I hope it helps.